# How to properly set a main working directory for a Python project

Tags: python, project-structure, working-directory

Let us assume I have the following folder structure:

```
/path/to/project/directory/
|- MyProject/
   |- Scripts/
      |- Analysis/
         |- myanalysis.py
      |- Modelling/
         |- mymodel1.py
         |- mymodel2.py
         |- mymodel3.py
      |- Testing/
         |- mytest.py
      |- Function/
         |- myfunction.py
   |- Files/
      |- data.csv
```

I want to achieve that when running any of the Python scripts, the working directory is always automatically set to `/path/to/project/directory/MyProject`. It should be a relative path such that someone else can also run the scripts. What would be the best practice to achieve that? Would I need to add a config or ini file? If yes, how would this file need to look like?

I am coming from a R background where you can set R-Projects which automatically set the working directory to the file location of the R-Project file. I want to achieve something like that.

Thanks!

Comment: See https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/structure/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many options:

1. Create virtual env, declare a variable (on a .env file) and use it always as needed
2. Create a configs.py file and import it everywhere
3. import os
   #run this before your code to set current path
   #(create a function that executes before everything)
   os.chdir(default_path)

Comment: Thanks, for the answer! Would it be sufficient to place the configs.py file in the "Scripts" folder or do I need to have a configs.py file in each of my subfolders (Analysis, Modelling, Testing,...) as well?

Comment: you can define in your main folder, and then call it with relative imports.